Cómo abrir una aplicacion usando js en el navegador
Buenas si ya saben que existe una web llamada bananagame que es para descargar mods de worldbox. Lo interesante viene cuando intento descargar directamente un mod al juego y bananagame pide el permiso del usuario para abrir worldbox.exe. Si alguien sabe como hacer eso con js me diga por favor

En realidad eso no es cosa de javascript. Creo que es una asociación de links a nivel del sistema operativo. Por ejemplo, si abres una URL que comienza por "whatsapp://" se abre WhatsApp. https://stackoverflow.com/q/80650/ https://stackoverflow.com/q/33248766/

Muchas gracias bro

Una URI (Identificador uniforme de recursos) tiene el siguiente formato:

Aquí una lista de scheme reconocidos
En la práctica (y en términos simples) lo que hace el sistema operativo es asociar un scheme con un programa ejecutable, a esto se le llama Protocolo. Entonces al accionar una URI el sistema operativo abre la aplicación asociada y entrega el resto de la URI (del scheme a la derecha) como parámetros de inicio.
Es así, que cuando presionas a:
https://es.stackoverflow.com
El sistema abre el programa asociado a HTTPS, es decir el navegador predeterminado y le entrega es.stackoverflow.com para que haga algo con ese dato (ir a ese sitio en el caso del navegador).
Mismo caso con otros tipos enlaces comunes:


<a href="mailto:bill@microsoft.com">Abre el cliente de correo predeterminado</a><br>
<a href="ftp://ftp.example.com/file.txt">Abre el cliente de FTP</a><br>
<a href="tel:+1234567890">Abre la aplicación de llamadas</a>




Tú puedes definir un Custom Protocol para asociar un scheme con una aplicación. Esto se realiza a nivel de sistema operativo, por tanto, solo será compatible en los computadores que hayas realizado esa configuración, y el cómo realizar la configuración varía según el sistema operativo
Lo que hacen las aplicaciones con instalador, es que al momento de instalar realizan aquella configuración
En Windows, los protocolos se configuran en registros (regedit.exe para ver el registro) y en la primera carpeta HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT se encuentran dichos protocolos, ahí te encontrarás con los antes mencionados como HTTP,HTTPS, FTP, MAILTO. Para agregar uno nuevo debes agregar una nueva entrada tal como indica los enlaces propuestos por @Mateo -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008905/20875970

En la antigüedad, habría técnicas para abrir aplicaciones directamente desde el navegador, recuerdo que con ActiveX se podía y me parece que con applet también se podía. Esto fue parcheado por los evidentes riesgos de seguridad que existen.

Graciass Yussef
